# Sql Query / Calculate rank for values based on date and id

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hiveql

> For each date and id we have to give the rank to values in decreasing order.
>
> Below is the Input Table.

```
>input data
+------------+----+-------+
|    date    | id | value |
+------------+----+-------+
| 01-01-2018 | A  |    20 |
| 01-01-2018 | A  |    50 |
| 01-01-2018 | C  |    40 |
| 01-01-2018 | B  |    40 |
| 02-01-2018 | A  |    30 |
| 03-01-2018 | C  |    20 |
| 03-01-2018 | C  |    40 |
| 04-01-2018 | B  |     0 |
| 04-01-2018 | B  |    40 |
| 05-01-2018 | B  |    70 |
+------------+----+-------+
```

> Output should look like below:

```
>output data
+------------+----+-------+------+
|    date    | id | value | rank |
+------------+----+-------+------+
| 01-01-2018 | A  |    50 |    1 |
| 01-01-2018 | A  |    20 |    2 |
| 01-01-2018 | B  |    40 |    1 |
| 01-01-2018 | C  |    40 |    1 |
| 02-01-2018 | A  |    30 |    1 |
| 03-01-2018 | C  |    40 |    1 |
| 03-01-2018 | C  |    20 |    2 |
| 04-01-2018 | B  |    40 |    1 |
| 04-01-2018 | B  |     0 |    2 |
| 05-01-2018 | B  |    70 |    1 |
+------------+----+-------+------+
```

Comment: Which one of them is your DBMS? and what have you tried to solve the problem so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RANK()`, partitioning on `date` and `id` and ordering by `value` descending:

```
SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date, id ORDER BY value DESC) AS ranking
FROM data
```

Output:

```
date        id  value   ranking
01-01-2018  A   50      1
01-01-2018  A   20      2
01-01-2018  B   40      1
01-01-2018  C   40      1
02-01-2018  A   30      1
03-01-2018  C   40      1
03-01-2018  C   20      2
04-01-2018  B   40      1
04-01-2018  B   0       2
05-01-2018  B   70      1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d68fd/2)

This query will run on all the DBMS you have tagged your question with.